# Validate the Sign-up Password of user in React-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase for Creating an Authentication Page, What I am trying to do is to not give an error when the password is at least 6 chars long, has at least one uppercase and one lowercase character.
What should I do to execute the upper conditions?

```
  const handleSignup = () => {
    fire
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((err) =>{
      switch (err.code){
        case "auth/invalid-email":
        case "auth/email-already-in-use":
          setEmailError(err.message);
          break;
        case "auth/weak-password":
          setPasswordError(err.message)
          break;
            
      }
    })
  }
```

Here I have provided the error when the password is less than 6 characters, How can I provide the error for not having atleast one-uppercase and one-lowercase.

Comment: It looks like Firebase doesn't have an upper/lower case requirement, so you would have to test for that yourself and then only create the user if the password passes your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth only requires your password to be at least 6 characters long.

You can add your own validation check before calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`

```
// contains at least one uppercase and one lower case character
/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/.test(password)
```

But consider that a client side validation can be bypassed, and so your security concept should not rely on this custom validation. It can help users to choose a secure password though.

Comment: is this really a security risk?

Comment: Depends on the security requirements. If Firebase password security is not sufficient for the questioner he should consider, that a client side validation can not guarantee lower and uppercase letters for all users.

Comment: of course, by considering that people which can bypass frontend validation also surely know more about cyber security and by bypassing this validation, they put into the risk just their data in the database. Thats why i asked if its really a security risk. 
Anyway, you are right. :)

Comment: I would phrase it like that: If I'm not satisfied with the security that firebase provides, I should not use it.